# R: apply function over multiple columns by condition (like with aggregate)

Tags: r

I had a hard time describing this one but here is my example:

```
n=20
years= c(rep(2000,n), rep(2001,n), rep(2002,n), rep(2003,n), rep(2004,n))
val1= c(rep(7,n), rep(8,n), rep(9,n), rep(10,n), rep(11,n))
val2= c(rep(1:20,5))

tmp= cbind(val1,val2,years)

test= array(dim=c(2,100,3), dimnames= list(c("site1","site2"),NULL,c("val1","val2","years")))
test[1,,]= tmp
test[2,,]= tmp
```

So what I want to do is (val1*val2)/sum(val1) for every year, and in the end I want the output to be

```
site1 2000 value
site1 2001 value
.......
site2 2000 value
site2 2001 value
site2 2002 value
... and so on
```

Comment: There's something unclear about your formula `(val1*val2)/sum(val1)`. The `sum(val1)` in the denominator makes sense; that aggregates on `val1`. But the `(val1*val2)` in the numerator does not aggregate. How do you want to aggregate the multiple `val1` and `val2` values that exist for each `site`/`year` group in the numerator?

Comment: If you're going to get a single value for each `site`/`year` group, then you need to aggregate into a single value at some point.

Comment: Or do you *not* want to aggregate, thereby getting a vector of values for each `site`/`year` group?

Comment: The only reason I mention aggregate is because its the only function I know that will do functions by unique groups.  I need the function to multiply the columns val1 and val2 row by row, so every row has the product of the two columns and then the sum of those products are divided by the sum of val1, but this is all done for every year. See my comment for adana's answer too.

Comment: So you mean `sum(val1*val2)/sum(val1)`?

Comment: Oh I see, and yes you are correct.  Thanks for your responses!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [`tapply()`](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/tapply.html) to do this:

```
tapply(seq_len(prod(dim(test)[1:2])),list(rownames(test)[row(test[,,1L])],test[,,'years']),function(g) sum(test[,,'val1'][g]*test[,,'val2'][g])/sum(test[,,'val1'][g]));
##       2000 2001 2002 2003 2004
## site1 10.5 10.5 10.5 10.5 10.5
## site2 10.5 10.5 10.5 10.5 10.5
```

You can reshape afterward to get the required output. I figured out how to use [`reshape()`](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/stats/html/reshape.html) to do this, but it's ugly. I had to use nearly every argument accepted by the function to customize the result to match the required output. Assuming you store the above result as `res`, we have:

```
reshape(data.frame(res,site=rownames(res),stringsAsFactors=F,check.names=F),dir='l',idvar='site',varying=seq_len(ncol(res)),times=colnames(res),v.names='value',timevar='year',new.row.names=seq_len(prod(dim(res))));
##     site year value
## 1  site1 2000  10.5
## 2  site2 2000  10.5
## 3  site1 2001  10.5
## 4  site2 2001  10.5
## 5  site1 2002  10.5
## 6  site2 2002  10.5
## 7  site1 2003  10.5
## 8  site2 2003  10.5
## 9  site1 2004  10.5
## 10 site2 2004  10.5
```

Comment: Perhaps it would be better for testing purposes if the test data didn't result in the same value for all groups.

Comment: I ran this code and it works, but it seems that the compute time is exponential, not linear.  I have transects that group a different amount of sites together.  It takes 1.34 seconds/site to run 76 sites and 3.78 seconds/site to run 172 sites.  When I get to my largest transect of almost 500 sites it takes for ever.  Any idea why the timing is exponential?  I have plenty of ram for the operation (4-5 free gigs)

Answer (score 0):

Declare a function which perform the operation required in a given dimension

```
library(dplyr)

getValues<-function(name){
temp<-data.frame(test[name,,])
values<- temp %>% group_by(years) %>% mutate(value=val1*val2/sum(val1)) %>% select(years,value)
data.frame(cbind(values,name)
}
```

Apply the function on any matrix in the first dimension

```
listTemp<-lapply(dimnames(test)[[1]],getValues)
```

Use the function in the data.table package to efficiently bind data frames

```
library(data.table)
allData<-rbindlist(listTemp)
```

Comment: Adiana thanks for your response!  Correct me if I am wrong but I believe it is missing the one crucial part I can't figure out: the (x1*x2)/sum(x1) has to be done over every year, where each data frame has multiple years.  This is why I was having trouble- essentially I wanted to use apply for the three dimensional array and aggregate so that it would give me an answer for every year (apply, c(1), fun=aggregate(x,by=list(x$year, fun=(x1*x2)/sum(x1)).  However, aggregate only works on one vector so I could not use both x1 and x2.